# Avoid overlap Android Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout, overlap

I would like to avoid "Status" of being written on two lines, I'm using constraint layout. I looked other similar questions but I did not find how to solve the problem.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
  As recommended by Google, we use a ConstraintLayout
  as the root element
  We add a padding all around using the padding attribute
-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    >

    <!--
    * We use the hint attribute to display the "type" string
    * The type string has been extracted into a dedicated file
    * The width is "0dp" because the "match_parent" value cannot be
    used with the constraintLayout
    * We use the inputType attribute to display the best keyboard
    to the user
    *
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/price"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/status"
        android:text="Status :"
        android:textStyle=""
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/status_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/status_label"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the view:
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmPm6.png)

Hope you'll provide some solutions.

Comment: Wrap your textview and spinner in linearlayout, and also set padding/margin accordingly.

Comment: You can make the width of `status_label` to `wrap_content`

Comment: It may also work if you just remove app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/status"

Comment: @KrishnaSharma yes it works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the width of `status_label` to `wrap_content`

Comment: It would be great if you accept this answer so that others also get a help from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
>

<!--
* We use the hint attribute to display the "type" string
* The type string has been extracted into a dedicated file
* The width is "0dp" because the "match_parent" value cannot be
used with the constraintLayout
* We use the inputType attribute to display the best keyboard
to the user
*
-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/status"
    android:text="Status :"
    android:textStyle=""
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/status_label"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/status_label"
    />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
And here

Comment: It does not work, the status text view is just moving down a bit but nothing changes about the overlapping